# Angular Universal State Transfer Initializer

Tags: angular, angular-universal

How to use correctly this module https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/common/src/state-transfer-initializer

After removing document DOMContentLoaded and using this module state transfer stops working in browser. What is the proper way to use this module?

P.S. Has been fixed in @nguniversal/common@7.1.0 release, PR https://github.com/angular/universal/commit/0e38dd1

Comment: This is a nice problem and I proposed the same answer to Angular Universal and they accepted it and recently it got merged to Angular Universal. https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/common/src/state-transfer-initializer/module.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If `DOMContentLoaded` event already fired and after adding a listener
>   for `DOMContentLoaded` event, then it will not execute.
>
> We can check whether document is loaded or not by the following check.
>
> ```
> if (doc.readyState === "complete" || doc.readyState === "interactive") {
>     // document is ready
> }
> ```
>
> If `DOMContentLoaded` is not fired then we can listen to it.
>
> ```
> function handler() {
>     // After DOMContentLoaded
> }
> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
> ```

So we need to `resolve()` the promise if `DOMContentLoaded` already fired. I modified the `StateTransferInitializerModule` module code of **[Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/common/src/state-transfer-initializer/module.ts)** and following is the code.

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export function domContentLoadedFactory(doc: Document) {
  return () => new Promise ((resolve, _reject) => {
    const contentLoaded = () => {
      doc.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contentLoaded);
      resolve();
    };
    if (doc.readyState === "complete" || doc.readyState === "interactive") {
      // if DOMContentLoaded already fired
      // document is already ready to go
      resolve();
    }
    else{
      // if DOMContentLoaded is not fired then we are listening the event.
      doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contentLoaded);
    }
  });
}


@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, multi: true, useFactory: domContentLoadedFactory, deps: [DOCUMENT]},
  ]
})
export class StateTransferInitializerModule {

}
```

For reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vregle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdom-content-loaded.module.ts) code.